# Leaky ReLU inside of a Simple Python Neural Net

Tags: python, neural-network, activation-function

To build a simple 1-layer neural network, many tutorials use a sigmoid function as the activation function. According to scholarly articles and other online sources, a leaky ReLU is a better alternative; however, I cannot find a way to alter my code snippet to allow a leaky ReLU.

I tried logic like `if x > 0 then x else x/100` as the activation function, then the same for the derivative.

Is it failing because the output layer cannot have a ReLU? Should I change the first layer to ReLU then add a softmax output layer?

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

X = np.array([[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]])
y = np.array([[0,1,0,1]]).T

class NN:
  def __init__(self, X, y):
    self.X = X
    self.y = y
    self.W = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (X.shape[1], 1))
    self.b = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (X.shape[1], 1))

  def nonlin(self, x, deriv=False):
    if deriv:
      return x*(1-x)
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

  def forward(self):
    self.l1 = self.nonlin(np.dot(self.X, self.W + self.b))
    self.errors = self.y - self.l1
    print(abs(sum(self.errors)[0]))

  def backward(self):
    self.l1_delta = self.errors * nonlin(self.l1, True)
    self.W += np.dot(self.X.T, self.l1_delta)
    self.b += np.dot(self.X.T, self.l1_delta)

  def train(self, epochs=20):
    for _ in range(epochs):
      self.forward()
      self.backward()

nn = NN(X, y)
nn.train()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the task you're working on is a binary classification task since `y = np.array([[0,1,0,1]]).T`. And as an error function you use `self.errors = self.y - self.l1`. Now compare this to the curve of a leaky ReLU function:

[image: Leaky ReLU]

The leaky ReLU is an unbounded function. How is your network supposed to model a binary classification task where output values are elements of $\{0,1\}$ using this function? And what is the result of applying the absolute difference as an error function to your labels $y \in \{0,1\}$ and your outputs $\hat{y} \in (-\infty,\infty)$?

What you would need is a translation of the lReLU outputs to your classes, e.g. something like `prediction = 1.0 if activation >= 0.0 else 0.0`.

Which is one reason why it is more common to apply last layer activation functions to classification problems which can be interpreted as class probabilities, e.g. Softmax or Sigmoid:

[image]

You still need a threshold here to move from real valued outputs (which are interpreted as probabilities) to binary class labels but that is fairly straightforward since often you just set it to a probability of $0.5$.

I suggest to go follow a tutorial for your from scratch implementation. If you are willing to take a step back [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-perceptron-algorithm-scratch-python/) is one for a simple percepton (i.e. just a single neuron).

---

Images taken from [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/activation-functions-neural-networks-1cbd9f8d91d6) article